# Streaming from webcam to server using flask-socketio

Tags: flask, websocket, socket.io, video-streaming, flask-socketio

I am trying to build a web application where images are streamed from a client's webcam to a server, the server performs some computations on the images, and the results of those computations are sent back to the client, all in real time.

So far, I have tried it with **flask-socketio**, adapting this code:

https://github.com/dxue2012/python-webcam-flask

which is again I think adapted from this example:

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-video-streaming

Relevant code bits on the client's side are:

```js
function sendSnapshot() {
  if (!localMediaStream) {
    return;
  }

  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight, 0, 0, 300, 150);

    let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
      socket.emit('input image', dataURL);
  }

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    localMediaStream = stream;

    setInterval(function () {
      sendSnapshot();
    }, 50);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

And on the server:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

socketio = SocketIO(app)


val = 0

@socketio.on('input image', namespace='/test')
def test_message(input):
    input = input.split(",")[1]

    global val
    val = do_stuff(input)

@socketio.on('get value', namespace='/test')
def send_stuff_back():

    global val

    emit("val ready", val)
```

Other than in the GitHub example I don't need to send images back to the client, only much smaller data.

The problem is, even so, everything is extremely laggy unless the images sent to the server are impermissibly small, i.e., to the point where it really defeats the purpose of sending them to a server in the first place.

The problem persists if the image computations are skipped, the problem seems to lie in sending the images.

Now I'm wondering whether that's expected behavior of this canvas/toDataURL method of streaming or if I'm doing something wrong.

If this is expected, maybe someone could point me in the direction of a more practical way of achieving what I'm trying to do.

(eventlet is definitely installed; I'm using heroku to deploy in case that's relevant.)

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit 1**:

I've already increased 'max_decode_packets' so that's not the source of the problem.

**Edit 2**:

Network:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwW6p.png)

**Edit 3**:

More screenshots:
Network, websocket message [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3Koj.png)
server->client[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzYaj.png)

Comment: Is your client getting a WebSocket connection? That would be the first thing to check.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the network dev tools upon opening the page. It shows that websockets are used. There's also a barrage of GET/POST with 400: BAD REQUEST in the console if that's any indication ...

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to all of this and just stumbled upon the "Message" feature: it looks like there's really no problem in terms of upload speed, also with reasonably sized images (see added screenshots, edit 3). What's strange though is that the data sent from the server to the client in "printval" comes in irregular bursts. I'd expect it to follow a pattern of 1. "input image", 2. "getval", 3. "printval", repeat.

Comment: Never mind, those green messages don't mean that the images were successfully uploaded, and the irregular messages back from the server suggest that they weren't. Sorry, again, I'm new to this.

Comment: Start by addressing the 400 errors, that's not normal, each time you get one of those the client needs to reconnect. Enable the Socket.IO logs on the server to see if there are any clues there.

Comment: Thanks @Miguel, I'll try that!